# wget a file, logging the output and showing the output on prompt

Tags: bash, shell-script, logs, wget, output

In a bash script, I must download a file from the web. I use the `wget` command for doing this. I would like to log the output of the `wget` command, and at "the same time" have the output prompting on terminal.

I searched in the `man wget` without finding the way to achieve that.

It seems that if you turn on the log with `-o` or `-a` parameter, then the prompt output is automatically 'redirected' to the log file, and nothing is shown on the terminal while executing the script, until it has completed the download.

> wget -a wget_log --no-check-certificate --auth-no-challenge
>   --http-user=$jen_uname --http-password=$jen_psswd link_to_the_file

Is it possible to do both? Output on prompt and writing on log file?

Comment: Just to be clear - you want the output of `wget` to go both to a log file and to the terminal?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You use the lovely `tee` command to do this:

```
wget --no-check-certificate --auth-no-challenge --http-user=$jen_uname --http-password=$jen_psswd 2>&1 | tee -a wget_log
```

THe `2>&1` means that STDERR goes to the same place as STDOUT, and they're both piped to `tee`. The `-a` means append. `tee` will then send the output both to wget_log and to STDOUT.

Comment: great! thankyou jenny for the clear explaination!

Comment: `wget` is just outputting to STDOUT -- `tee` is designed specifically for outputting to a file and STDOUT at the same time. `man tee` doesn't make this clear.  -- ( 2&>1 stderr is redirected to stdout so errors come along for the ride).